# IV plot for NPN BJT

Tags: bjt, npn, orcad

I have done a “parametric sweep” of the DC voltage source VCC ranging from 0 to 30 V and on the current source with values of iB = 0,50,100,150,200, and 250 µA.

[image: NPN BJT]

Below is the plot iC vs vCE (vCE being the X axis). The X axis shows only values from 0 to 10 V.

[image: iv plot]

Why is there only 5 lines on the plot if I have swept iB for 6 values?

Comment: As a sanity check you could plot Ib and ensure you are getting 6 sweeps

Comment: why do you show only 4 step currents in 1 unlabelled plot?  for an unidentified setup?

Comment: You say you plotted 6, you ask why you only see 5, I see 4.  What's R_C and Beta?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I believe the 5th (and maybe 6th, I need to do the math) is displayed as cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

I plotted Ib as a sanity check and got 5 values, so I added 300uA to the sweep. This gave me six sweeps with 250uA included.

This is the the iv plot with Ib.
[image: iv plot w/ Ib]

This is the the iv plot with Ic.
[image: iv plot with Ic]

The fact that there is one fewer curve than expected is just an issue with OrCAD. I did a DC Sweep w/ secondary sweep (the primary was for Vcc) with initial point I=0.1uA (since we cannot start from exactly 0), ending point of 300uA and increments of 50uA.